# Role of foreign key in bidirectional relationships

Tags: mysql, database, orm, entity-relationship

I am a little confused about designing the database for a bidirectional relationship between a customer & product.

Just to be clear a bidirectional relationship ensures that a customer is aware of his products & a product is aware of it's customer.

I have a Customer table & a Product table. Product table has a foreign key of Customer table.

To create a bidirectional relationship should a Customer table also contain a foreign key of Product table? I've seen ORM [examples](http://fruzenshtein.com/bidirectional-many-to-one-association/) where just one FK reference is OK for a bidirectional relationship but still a little confused, can anyone enlighten me on this?

What difference would it make if I put a FK of Product table in the Customer table?

Comment: An FK of product in the customer table would presume that a customer can only be associated with (at most) one product. As it stands, a product can only be associated with one customer.

Comment: thanks Strawberry, my doubt is cleared. :)

Comment: so that means unidirectional & bidirectional relationships solely depend on orm mapping? Please write an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: ...as opposed to...?

Comment: In real environment there should not be any relationship between customer and product table, even you should create a junction table as Gordon suggested which should be associated with both tables means have only customers those exist in customer table and same for product.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want a `CustomerProducts` table, to represent the relationship:

```
create table CustomerProducts (
     CustomerProductId int not null auto_increment primary key,
     CustomerId int not null,
     ProductId int not null,
     Amount int not null,
     . . .
     foreign key (CustomerId) references Customers(CustomerId),
     foreign key (ProductId) references Products(ProductId)
);
```

This is called a "junction" table.  It can have additional columns (such as `Amount`) specifying characteristics of the relationship.

Comment: While not wrong, I think the surrogate key is (potentially) misleading.

Comment: Gordon Customer & Products are in a onetomany relationship. My folly I should have specified in the question.